# What is best algorithm to sort documents for ranking using pairwise comparison

Tags: sorting, machine-learning, ranking, information-retrieval, pairwise

I am working on an information retrieval problem statement. I have trained a deep learning model using the pairwise approach. And NDCG and MAP are very good compared to the pointwise approach, but it is bringing extra computation. While inference I have to rank 10k documents at once, In pairwise I have to create all possible pairs and then I will be able to rank based on the result of the pairwise model or I can apply to merge sort. Using this approach we cant deploy our model in production because it will too long to rank the documents.

**So I am looking for an optimized sorting algorithm for the pairwise ranking model.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up ELO ranking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ranking from pairwise comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789787/ranking-from-pairwise-comparisons)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this will give a bit noisy ranking which we can't afford for our product.